# Ordered single pass pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to process a csv containing rows with `start_time` and `end_time` to get the number of concurrent sessions. I'd like to iterate in a single pass over the data sorted by timestamp, and maintain an accumulator-like variable that keeps the number of active sessions, then do some other processing. To keep the accumulator accurate, I'd need to ensure that the order is guaranteed over the whole RDD (so I can't use `map` or `forEach`).

The database is small enough that no parallelization is fine for this operation, but large enough that it won't fit in RAM. `toLocalIterator()` actually does what I want, but I can't figure out how I would do parallelized operations afterwards.

Thanks!

Example code:

```
concurrent = 0 
sessions = sc.parallelize([
    {start_time: '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', end_time: '2016-01-01T00:01:00.000Z'}, ... ]) 
events = sessions.flatMap(separate_end_time).sortBy(lambda x: x['timestamp']) 
    # RDD [{timestamp: '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', change: 1}, 
    #      {timestamp: '2016-01-01T00:10:00.000Z', change: -1}, ...] 

events.forEach(apply_accumulator)   # <- replace this forEach!

def apply_accumulator(session): 
    global concurrent  
    concurrent += change 
    session['concurrent'] = concurrent
```

Comment: Use toLocalIterator and discard collected results?

Comment: I'd like to modify the value of the `events` RDD though by adding a property, so I'm not sure how discarding the collected results would work. I could create a new array of the new property using toLocalIterator, then zip and map, but ideally there would be a way to convert to a "non-local iterator"